# How to escape HTML special characters when rendering a PDF using EJS and WKHTMLTOPDF?

Tags: express, pdf, escaping, diacritics, html-characters

I have an express application that generates pdf documents. I use `ejs` as a template engine and then I use `wkhtmltopdf`.

```js
ejs.renderFile(
    path.join(__dirname, 'pages', 'lettera.ejs'),
    {
      ...some variables
    },
    (err, str) => {
      wkhtmltopdf(str, { output: `${dir}/lettera.pdf` });
    },
  );
```

The problem is that accent letters don't get escaped. For example `Venerdì` becomes `VenerdÃ¬`. If I escape the variable manually with `escape` from `lodash` I get the full code: `Venerdì` => `Venerd&igrave;`.

How can I get the real accent letters?